# How to send a token through a socket

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

After registration or authorization, the server sends the user a token. For a client I use a react.

For example this.

```
{
    token: 'yJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsEKJhiqAI8ACCtU0F5HTCSgC9GsQEG02Lg'
}
```

When a user wants to send a message to the chat, he must send this token to the server.

How to transfer a token to the server?

I implemented it like this.

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const your_jwt = 'yJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsEKJhiqAI8ACCtU0F5HTCSgC9GsQEG02Lg';

const socket = io('http://localhost:8081', {
    query: `token=${your_jwt}`,
});
```

By sending so the token is not safe. Can I send a tonk in the header?

I tried to do it like this.

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:8081', {
    extraHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${your_jwt}`,
    },
});
```

But the token does not come to the server in the header.